# How to make an on-hover bottom border overlap div below?

Tags: css, border

I have a horizontal navigation menu using unordered lists. Under the menu there is a straight gray line which has to have 100% width of the parent container. When hovering the list elements, the part of the line has to be colored blue right under the list element. I can't find any suitable way of doing this. I got it working with position:relative and adding top:14px but it isn't really satisfying me since any changes to the font size or font face will destroy everything. I also thought about changing margins between elements to padding, increasing li's height and giving each one the same gray border and just changing it's color on hover, but I need the line to go all along the parent div's width.
How it has to look:
[expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgV6C.png)

My current code:

```css
#container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: white;
}

#container ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#container ul li {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

#container ul li:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

#container ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

#container ul li a:hover {
  color: grey;
}

#container #slider {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">INDEX</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">HELP</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">LONG LINK TEXT</a></li>
  </ul>
  <span id="slider"></span>
</div>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9fhvyk76/3/

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use a pseudo element so you have more control over the size/position without really needing to change much. Just add position: relative to the link itself so the pseudo's scale and positioning are associated with it. Let me know if this is what you were looking for!

https://jsfiddle.net/g00jrsqf/

```
#container ul li a{
   position: relative;
}
#container ul li a:after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  background: #01a2e8;
  opacity: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -29px;
}
#container ul li:hover a:after{
  opacity: 1;
}
```